# noindex, nofollow for entire Wordpress installation in a subdirectory?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, seo, nofollow, noindex

So, I have Wordpress running in the root directory of my webspace; I'll install another Wordpress instance in a subdirectory of the same server in a couple of days for testing purposes. So here's the thing, I don't want this Wordpress instance, any of it's pages, posts or *anything* from that subdirectory to show up in Google and the like. So I'm looking for a way to apply noindex, nofollow (and what else?) to this subdirectory and all files and subdirectories in it. What is the easiest way to achieve this (for example, can I use the .htaccess file, or is there a wordpress plugin that does this for me)?

I't very important that the main Wordpress installation and it's SEO are not affected by this.

Comment: There is a checkbox in the admin area under Settings which discourages search engines from indexing the site. Note, even with noindex set, you can't guarantee some search engines won't crawl (and index) your site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your Dashboard go to:

- Settings -> Reading
- In Reading, near the bottom of the screen there is an option called "Site Visibility"
- Change that option to "Discourage search engines from indexing this site"
- Save those changes

[image]

Refresh the site and take a look at the source, there is now a `<meta name='robots' content='noindex,follow' />` on each page. Also in the robots.txt file there is not the following

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```